# Rigid body animation plays fine in viewport, but once rendered the object behaves differently

Tags: particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I've never struggled so much with a file/animation.

The rope just falls through the cylinder when animating. Why is this?

Eevee does the same thing.

Hoe can I send the file to someone to please assist?

I also need the rope to continue wrapping, and extend past 250 frames.

Below is the link to the file:

[image]

[image: screen capture]

[[image: screen capture 2][2]]

Comment: To share the file use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help,  then come back to this page and [**edit**] the question to add the link to the file in it it.

Comment: It looks like that link is not valid.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=kME8VKSs" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/kME8VKSs/)

Comment: Ok some of those seem to be what I'm looking for. Is there a way to open my file and apply the same attributes? Or is there a blend file for the third gif you sent?

Comment: What I really want/need is someone to take the file and make edits to it, and show me how they did it - IF that's possible.

Comment: This is for a project for a client. I need it soon.

Comment: Is there a way for the third gif of the spinning fast wrapping action to have the rope more thicker? Do you have the blend file?

Comment: Apologies for not replying sooner.  Your comments didn't show up on my message indicator, nor did I get any email.  I've been checking your post for a while and must have missed the 'See more comments'.  See next...